# Можно ли пользоваться nodeJS вместо PHP на Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, node.js

Собственно в этом и есть вопрос. Я читал, что с 2020 Wordpress поставляется вместе с `React`. Хотелось бы иметь возможность и бэкенд писать на `js`, так как его немного знаю. Возможно ли это? Или чтобы начать работать с этой CMS все-таки придется учить PHP?

Comment: Нет, сорри )) Весь бэкенд ядра на php.

Comment: Можно, если вы всё на ноду перепишите с php

Comment: @InDevX вы только представьте, что будет, если это случится) CMS на пыхе, CMS на жс-е))